# Did Obi-Wan ever wonder why he failed to defeat Count Dooku when rescuing Palpatine?

Tags: star-wars, obi-wan-kenobi

I ask this question based on a comment by @MooS https  on this answer: [Why was Obi-Wan was so confident about Count Dooku? Was he arrogant?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/152604/why-was-obi-wan-was-so-confident-about-count-dooku-was-he-arrogant/152606#152606)

> Palpatine uses the force to make Obi-Wan unable to defend himself, since he wants Anakin to beat Dooku. Obi-Wan cannot block this since he does not suspect it at all.

Did Obi-wan ever try to understand why he failed to beat Dooku here, or did he assume that he was no match for Dooku, or did he simply ignore it and move on?

Comment: I'm currently asking him tehre where he got that info from.....that is the first time I ever read anything indicating that Palpatine interfered in that fight oO

Comment: Note that it seems that this conclusion of mine is opinion based, since it is neither stated in the script nor in the novel. But as far as I am concerned, I think this conclusion seems kinda legit by what you see in the movie. Palpatine is shown mutiplie times during this scene and his facial expression suggests that he seems to either have diarrhea or he is interfering the fight.

Comment: Since this question is based on a misnomer (that Palpatine *made Obi-Wan fail in his fight with Dooku*) you might want to reconsider your core question.

Comment: "he seems to either have diarrhea or he is interfering the fight" — we may be discounting option one too rashly.

Answer (score -2):

No, there was nothing like that. 
Dooku used the force to throw Obi Wan while Anakin being a powerful and more skilled Jedi did not give any opportunity to Dooku to do the same with him. The problem lay with Anakin as he was angry which made him turn to the dark side. 
Obi wan had not made any mistake nor he was arrogant.
You can say that Dooku was a powerful Sith Lord. He fought good with Yoda, remember!

Comment: Anakin was not a more skilled Jedi; he simply was not the target of a surprise force push that knocked Obi-Wan back and subsequently unconscious. Once your opponent performs a maneuver in front of you that knocks out your team mate, you watch out for it to happen again. Dooku knows this as well, and considering he easily bested Anakin the last time in a 1v1 duel, he does not feel the need to try and re-use that part of his arsenal so soon.